# what is the best practice for pre-processing before clustering algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis

my data contain several features on user level.
and my desire is to cluster them to several groups based on this features
my data is skewed with presence of extreme outliers for of some of the features.
my question is what is the best practice for pre-processing before the clustering algorithm ?

Comment: Try *scaling* the numeric features such that  all attributes have about the same order of magnitude.  Columns with NA values are problematic (so remove them if you can, re-add them later with NAs interpolated or imputed).

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for clustering is to first figure out how to measure distance reliably. Then many clustering methods can be tried.

But before you can quantify dissimilarity, the data cannot be used for most clustering.